# ParserError: Expected primary expression indicating "address public"

Tags: solidity, remix

How to solve this error? I remember last time I used this code without error, but don't know why now shown this.

```
address public commissionWallet = ; // The wallet for receive marketing funds
address public firstWallet = ; // The owner's wallet
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the error appears when you don't initialize variables with any values. In this case, you declared two address variable but didn't initialize them with some value.
In fact, when you use this statement:

```
address public commissionWallet = ;
```

After '=' symbol you must to initialize this variable with an address!

For example:

```
address public commissionWallet = 0x6E9c5b1B1BDFF92F8B5602D707E32BB405a1df7C;
address public firstWallet = 0x58F28F28FdE5F999fC88733F31eAa3F974DFAAec;
```

If you don't want initialize this variables when declare them, you can use this statement:

```
[typeof] [modifier] variableName;
```

In this last case, change your code in this way:

```
address public commissionWallet;
address public firstWallet;
```